# why does my loop skip an object in python?

Tags: python, class, for-loop, logic, artificial-intelligence

```
def resolveSentences(s1, s2):
"""
    given two sentences s1 and s2 return the resolved sentence
"""
clauses = []
for p1 in s1:
    for p2 in s2:
        if p1.name == p2.name and p1.sign != p2.sign:
            s1 = remove(p1,s1)
            s2 = remove(p2, s2)
            s = None
            if s1 and s2:
                s = list(set(s1).union(s2))
            elif s1 and not s2:
                s = list(set(s1))
            elif s2 and not s1:
                s = list(set(s2))
            if s:
                for pred in s:
                    clauses.append(pred)
if len(clauses)> 0:
    return clauses
else:
    return None
```

I call the function using:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = convertToPredicate("A(x)")
    p2 = convertToPredicate("B(x)")
    p3 = convertToPredicate("~A(x)")
    p4 = convertToPredicate("~B(x)")
    p5 = convertToPredicate("C(x)")
    s1 = [p1,p2,p5]
    # A(x)| B(x) | C(x)
    s2 = [p3,p4]
    # ~A(x)| ~B(x)
    trial = resolveSentences(s1,s2)
    for t in trial:
        print(t.sign, t.name, t.arguments, sep="\t")
```

My expected answer is:
 C(x)
My current answer is:
B(x)| ~B(x)| C(x)

**Question: Why doesn't it remove B(x)?**
My observation:
The first for loop skips the second predicate in the function resolveSentences(). I am not able to figure out why though. Any help would be appreciated.

The **remove** function is as follows:

```
def equals( p1, p2):
    """
        returns True is predicate p1 is equal to p2
    """
    if p1.name == p2.name:
        if p1.sign == p2.sign:
            return True
    return False

def remove( predicate_to_remove, sentence):
    """
        removes all instances of predicates from sentence and returns a list of predicates
    """
    for predicate in sentence:
        if equals(predicate_to_remove, predicate):
            sentence.remove(predicate)
    return sentence
```

**Predicate** is a class that has attributes: name, sign, constants, variables, arguments

the class defn for Predicate is:

```
class Predicate:
"""
    determining the contents of a predicate. 
    sign: 1 if negative, else positive
"""
name = None
sign = None
constants = None
variables = None
arguments = None

def __init__(self):
    self.arguments = []
    self.name = ""
    self.sign = 0
    self.constants = []
    self.variables = []
```

function convertToPredicate is:

```
def convertToPredicate(query):
"""
    converts the raw input to an object of class predicate
    (str) -> (Predicate)
"""
std_predicate = Predicate()

#determining sign of predicate
std_predicate.sign = 1 if query[0] == "~" else 0
query = query.replace("~","")

#determining name of predicate
std_predicate.name = query[:query.find("(")]

#determining arg/var/const of predicate
std_predicate.arguments = query[query.find("(")+1:query.find(")")].replace(" ", "").split(",")
for arg in std_predicate.arguments:
    if arg[0].isupper():
        std_predicate.constants.append(arg)
    elif arg[0].islower():
        std_predicate.variables.append(arg)
return std_predicate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) says this is expected:

> Note: There is a subtlety when the sequence is being modified by the
>   loop (this can only occur for mutable sequences, i.e. lists). An
>   internal counter is used to keep track of which item is used next, and
>   this is incremented on each iteration. When this counter has reached
>   the length of the sequence the loop terminates. This means that if the
>   suite deletes the current (or a previous) item from the sequence, the
>   next item will be skipped (since it gets the index of the current item
>   which has already been treated). Likewise, if the suite inserts an
>   item in the sequence before the current item, the current item will be
>   treated again the next time through the loop.

One way to avoid this is to drive the `for` loops using copies of the lists.
Instead of this:

```
for p1 in s1:
    for p2 in s2:
```

Use this:

```
base_s1 = s1[:]
base_s2 = s2[:]
for p1 in base_s1:
    for p2 in base_s2:
```

Since the loops use copies of `s1` and `s2`, changes to those lists in the loop body won't affect the values that `p1` and `p2` take on.